# É necessário ter o Node.js instalado para rodar um software com Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

Para um usuário executar um `.exe` de um software feito no Electron, ele precisa ter Node.js instado?

Answer (score 6):

> "*Ele permite desenvolver aplicações para desktop GUI usando componentes front end e back end originalmente criados para aplicações web: Node.js para o back end e Chromium para o front end.*" - [Wikipédia - Electron (software)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software))

Voltando à sua pergunta:

> Essa pessoa precisa ter Node.js instalado?

A resposta é **sim** e **não**. Vou te explicar o porquê!

O Electron, como já afirmado anteriormente, utiliza o Node.js no seu back-end. Mas isso não quer dizer que o usuário precise do Node.js instalado à parte.

Por exemplo: eu **não instalei** Node.js no meu computador. Mas instalei o Discord, que usa Electron. O que automaticamente instalou o Node.js.

Quando abro o Discord, (de cortesia) o Node.js é iniciado automaticamente:

[image: Gerenciador de tarefas - Node.js]

<sub>(Print do "Gerenciador de Tarefas")</sub>

Então, **sim**, o usuário precisa do Node.js instalado. E **não**, não precisa instalar ele à parte. O próprio Electron "prepara" o ambiente do usuário.

Comment: Não sabia que o Node era instalado também. +1 :) E se não tiver o Chromium, ele também é instalado automaticamente?

Comment: É, eu meio que sabia disso, exceto a parte da instalação das "dependências" automaticamente. Mas realmente, é o que mais faz sentido. Eu achava que era tudo já embutido no binário gerado. .-.

Comment: Quando disse binário, estava me referindo ao executável. O Node já vem incluso nele (no `.exe`)? Se sim, por que então ele é instalado à parte também?

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Obrigado _pelas ajudas_. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Com certeza não, o papel do Electron é interpretar JS + HTML e compilar um .exe (binário executável)

Comment: A pesar da baixa qualidade, a parte "***Com certeza não***" responde a pergunta. É interessante, sim, fundamentar a pergunta. Mas o resto da afirmação pode gerar uma confusão. Não é isso ao pé da letra.

Comment: Obrigado @LipEsprY